# My apexcharts does not update with axios (php - js)

Tags: javascript, php, json, axios, apexcharts

I have the following problem, I generate my chart with apexcharts but when I use axios to update it dynamically the data is not displayed.

`data_json.php`

```
<?php

    $sql = $conn->runQuery("SELECT * FROM data");
    $sql->execute();

    $data = [];
    while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $data[] = ["x" => $row['date'], "y" => $row['total']];
        }
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

The array returns the following data.

```
[
    {
        "x": "25 feb 2021",
        "y": "618.40"
    },
    {
        "x": "26 feb 2021",
        "y": "724.00"
    },
    {
        "x": "27 feb 2021",
        "y": "1298.00"
    },
    {
        "x": "28 feb 2021",
        "y": "777.60"
    }
]
```

the script to render the apexcharts

```
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            height:480,
        },

        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [],

        noData: {
            text: 'Loading...'
        },

        xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },
    }

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"),options);
    chart.render();

    var url = 'data_json.php';

    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
    }).then(function(response) {
        chart.updateSeries([{
            name: 'Sales',
            data: response.data
        }])
    })
```

Can you help me and tell me why it is not updating dynamically?

Comment: Code works fine with a mock axios call: https://jsfiddle.net/a0me6qg3/ Which most likely means that the axios call is failing. You can check what your PHP file is sending by visiting `http://localhost/data_json.php` (or similar)

Comment: I have checked what you indicate and it is ok, I will update the question and I will add the PHP code with which I generate the array, maybe you can see the error.

Comment: the question is updated.

Comment: You have `$data['data'][]`, which will create `{ "data": [...] }`. Thus the array is in `response.data.data` (axios has its own `.data`) ... :) Just use `$data[] = ["x" => ...` instead and it should work

Comment: I have just deleted what you indicate and it does not show any data.

Comment: The previous JSON output should have worked; you've since changed it to add the `"data"` layer, in accordance with your PHP code. If you change the PHP like I suggested, your JSON output should be just the array again, which should work with `response.data` in your JS code. Also, you can inspect the axios request and its result in the browser console.

Comment: this tells me.  "Uncaught ReferenceError: axios is not defined"

Comment: Well. You need to include the axios library if you want to use it; it's not built-in. I'd recommend to use fetch() instead, which *is* built-in, but you'd have to rewrite your JS code. Anyway, put this in your <head>: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bZS47S7sPOxkjU/4Bt0zrhEtWx0y0CRkhEp8IckzK+ltifIIE9EMIMTuT/mEzoIMewUINruDBIR/jJnbguonqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Yes, now it shows me the graph, thank you.